# jquery wrap every four child elements of a list element individually

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble to group elements inside a list element.

For excample I have three list elements:

```
<ul class="row">
<li class="item"> 
<!-- product name -->
<div class="imglist"> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"> 
    <!-- product name -->
    <div class="imglist"> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="row">
<li class="item"> 
<!-- product name -->
<div class="imglist"> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

In Jquery I tried this:

```
var divs = $("div.imglist > a");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>");
}
```

but now the result is that:

```
<ul class="row">
<li class="item"> 
<!-- product name -->
<div class="imglist"> 
<div class="group">
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a></div> 
</div>
</li>

<li class="item"> 
<!-- product name -->
<div class="imglist">
<div class="group">
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a>
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a></div> 
</div>
</li>

<li class="item"> 
<!-- product name -->
<div class="imglist">   
<div class="group">
<a href="#" title="image"><span class="txt">txt</span></a></div> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that I want the wrapping for each `li.item` individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through each list separately:

```
$('.imglist').each(function(){
    var divs = $('a', this);
    console.log(divs)
    console.log(divs.slice(0,4));
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
        console.log(i)
        divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DC2MC/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the grouping for each li.item:

```
$("ul li.item").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").wrapall("<div class='group'></div>");
});
```

Comment: How does this make groups of 4?